# substitute word separators with space

Tags: r, string, character, gsub

I just want to replace some word separators with a space.  Any hints on this? Doesn't work after converting to character either.

```
df <- data.frame(m = 1:3, n = c("one.one", "one.two", "one.three"))

> gsub(".", "\\1 \\2", df$n)
[1] "       "   "       "   "         "
> gsub(".", " ", df$n)
[1] "       "   "       "   "         "
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use regex for one-to-one character translation. You can use `chartr()`.

```
df$n <- chartr(".", " ", df$n)
df
#   m         n
# 1 1   one one
# 2 2   one two
# 3 3 one three
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
gsub("[.]", " ", df$n)
#[1] "one one"   "one two"   "one three"
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `fixed = TRUE` if you are looking for an exact match and don't need a regular expression.

```
gsub(".", " ", df$n, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "one one"   "one two"   "one three"
```

That's also faster than using an appropriate regex for such a case.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do like this,

```
gsub("\\.", " ", df$n)
```

OR

```
gsub("\\W", " ", df$n)
```

`\\W` matches any non-word character. `\\W+` matches one or more non-word characters. Use `\\W+` if necessary.